# How to get domain class output from db-reverse-engineer

Tags: postgresql, grails

I'm new to Grails - I using it with NetBeans and wanting to generate domain classes from my postgresql database using the db-reverse-engineer plugin.

However I can't get domain class output.

I have plugin configured in BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
    ...
    runtime ":db-reverse-engineer:0.5"
    ...
}
```

and following in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.reveng.packageName = "com.mycompany.db"
grails.plugin.reveng.includeTables = [ 'MyTable2' ]
grails.plugin.reveng.destDir = 'temp_reverse_engineer'
```

With debug on db-reverse classes enabled I get:

```
|Starting database reverse engineering, connecting to 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb' as 'postgres'
2014-07-03 12:20:34,126 [main] INFO  reveng.ReverseEngineerProgressListener  - Finding tables in org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.SchemaSelection@33e1fcdc
2014-07-03 12:20:34,198 [main] DEBUG reveng.GrailsReverseEngineeringStrategy  - table MyTable1 not included by name
2014-07-03 12:20:34,210 [main] INFO  reveng.ReverseEngineerProgressListener  - Found MyTable2
2014-07-03 12:20:34,211 [main] INFO  reveng.ReverseEngineerProgressListener  - Finding columns for public.MyTable2
2014-07-03 12:20:34,261 [main] INFO  reveng.ReverseEngineerProgressListener  - Finding exported foreignkeys on MyTable2
2014-07-03 12:20:34,392 [main] DEBUG reveng.GrailsPojoExporter  - grails.plugin.reveng.GrailsPojoExporter outputdir:C:\...\MyGrailsApplication\temp_reverse_engineer path: []
|Finished database reverse engineering
```

So the table I specify appears to be found by db-reverse-engineer and processed, but target directory remains empty.  I've tried with/without package and with package folder structure pre-created with no luck.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: What version of Grails do you use? I want to try to recreate your situation

Comment: When running in Netbeans it reports "Grails 2.3.8"

Comment: Ok, I'm already tried with grails-2.4 but failed with Transactions class not found. Now trying with grails-2.0.4.
Seems that plugin are too old for the newest Grails version )  
Please say yet your JDK version (6,7,8)

Comment: I've recreated your issue with Grails 2.3.8 & Java 6/7. And I've got the generated class that I've asked. But I've failed with Java 8. My DB is Postgres 9.2

Comment: @wwarlock - I'm running Netbeans 7.2 with Java 7. Postgres 9.3.4. I have not installed Grails - it's what comes with Netbeans.  Just to be clear - you say you have "recreated my issue" then "got the generated class" - my issue is I don't get a generated class (may be misreading what you've found)

Comment: Maybe that is my bad english )
I've repeated your steps but I've got reasonable result instead of you

Comment: Ok, I'm know write what I do:  
I have created the new grails project by `grails create-app`  
Then I'm added db-reverse-engineer plugin and specified settings for it.  
After that I've run the next command `grails clean && rm -rf target/ && grails test-app && grails prod db-reverse-engineer --stacktrace`  
  
`test-app` step is needed to install all plugins.  
And that's all I deed.